# Does DataFrame.loc[] method operate on reference, and DataFrame[col] by value?

Tags: python, pandas

In other languages, like C++, we have "pass-by-value" and "pass-by-reference" methods when passing argument to a function.

In Python, in particular Pandas, the [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) specifies differences in "returning a view vs a copy":

> (...) See that **getitem** in there? Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees), and therefore whether the **setitem** will modify dfmi or a temporary object that gets thrown out immediately afterward. That’s what SettingWithCopy is warning you about!

**Does "return by view" equals "pass by reference", and "return a copy" equals "pass by value"?**

An example I do not understand is the following code:

- I have used `.loc` in places that I consider suitable,
- but I'm still getting two "a value is trying to be set on a copy of the DataFrame" errors.

Why would this be the case?

```
for col in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
            'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 
            'j', 'k', 'h']:
    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x ** 2)

df.loc[:, 'a'] = df.a.astype(float) 
df.loc[:, 'a'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: If `df` is a copy of another data frame (e.g. `df = df_origin[[cols]]`) then you'd get this error independently of using `loc` or not

Comment: @RafaelC thanks for pointing this out! Very likely, I need to check the code on the other computer tomorrow.